# Correct answer but Runtime error at efficiency stage

Tags: c++, c++11, runtime-error

I was coding on an online site. Here, there are different stages of testing your implementation ie compilation, correctness and efficiency.

I was doing a question on [two pointers](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/container-with-most-water/#). Its statement is -

> Given n non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an,
>   where each represents a point at coordinate (i, ai).
>   'n' vertical lines are drawn such that the two endpoints of line i is at (i, ai) and (i, 0).
>
> Find two lines, which together with x-axis forms a container, such that the container contains the most water.
>
> Your program should return an integer which corresponds to the maximum area of water that can be contained

I got **correct answer** verdict but on stage to check efficiency it got runtime error. Now i have two questions(second follows first one)-

1) How can it have runtime error when it was given correct answer verdict in all test cases?

2) If it is really possible, can anyone help me find the error or possible reasons that this can happen?I cant find any no matter what i think:/

Code-

```
int finds(vector<bool>  arr){
    int i=0;
    while(arr[i]!=0)i++;
    return i;
}
int finde(vector<bool>  arr){
    int i=arr.size()-1;
    while(arr[i]!=0)i--;
    return i;
}
struct st{
    int data;
    int index;
};
int Solution::maxArea(vector<int> &A) {
    // Do not write main() function.
    // Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function.
    // Do not print the output, instead return values as specified
    // Still have a doubt. Checkout www.interviewbit.com/pages/sample_codes/ for more details
    int n=A.size(),ans=0;
    vector<bool> visited(n,0);
    int start=0,end=n-1;
    if(n<=1)return 0;

    vector<st> arr;
    st temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        temp.data=A[i];
        temp.index=i;
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](st a,st b)->bool{return a.data<=b.data;});

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
       // cout<<start<<"\t"<<end<<endl;
        ans=max(ans,arr[i].data*(arr[i].index-start));
        ans=max(ans,arr[i].data*(end-arr[i].index));
        visited[arr[i].index]=true;
        start=finds(visited);
        end=finde(visited);
        //cout<<"ans is "<<ans<<endl;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Error -

```
Runtime Error. Your submission stopped because of a runtime error. ex: division by zero, array index out of bounds, uncaught exception You can try testing your code with custom input and try putting debug statements in your code.

*** Error in `./solution': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000026227c0 ***

Aborted
```

Comment: 100% OT - Is there any reason to not pass `A` by const-reference? I see you are using a non-const one. Also instead of `finds` / `finde` you can use `std::find`.

Comment: @Holt what do ypu mean by OT? Nd there is so particular reason for not using const ref , its jst habit (which i will try to improve). Abt not using find, i prefer using my own functions instead of inbuilt as i know how they are working and helps in making functions that are more to my need than generic although many times it has caused me alot of problems too( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994718/why-does-an-inline-function-have-lower-efficiency-than-an-in-built-function?noredirect=1#comment76979854_44994718 ).

Comment: OT = Off-topic (my comment was not related to your problem). You should try to use the standard library as much as you can - Compilers are much better at optimizing their own stuffs than yours.

Comment: @Holt oh is that so? i can delete it but i dont know if deleting will result in deducting max's rep for correct answer(i wont want to delete it in that case:) )

Comment: I meant that my comment was off-topic for your question, not that your question is off-topic ;)

Comment: okay then. please dont scare small fries like me using high end words like OT next time:p

Comment: @Holt - OT: You've scared a monster :-)

Comment: @max66 that was so because this monster had intense war with a bug as a result this monster was in weakened state. if it would have been normal day this monster would not be scared so easily................. **well jst kidding**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that is your problem but could be a problem

In `maxArea()` You sort the `std::vector` `arr` with

```
sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),[](st a,st b)->bool{return a.data<=b.data;});
```

This is dangerous.

Try with "less" instead of "less or equal"; I mean

```
a.data < b.data;
```

instead of

```
a.data <= b.data;
```

The problem is that `std::sort()` require that the compare function (call it `comp()`) induce a strict weak ordering relation.

So it's required that `comp(a, a)` is **ever** false and that `comp(a, b) == true` imply that `comp(b, a) == false`.

Your (original) lambda function doesn't satisfies this requirements.

Comment: hmm i will keep that in mind from next time. nd let me try if changing it solves the prob or not

Comment: changing it really solved my problem. can you tell why it can be dangerous?

Comment: @monster The standard have *strict weak ordering* requirements on the `Compare` (3rd) argument of `std::sort`, if you do not respect, you fall into UB, so anything can happen.

Comment: @monster - answer modified (but the comment of Holt explain it also).

Comment: hmm ok thanks for the help guys. i dont know how much time it would have taken me if not for your help